# Stored procedure where statement containing many parameters

Tags: sql-server, azure, t-sql

I'm developing a lot of stored procedures, and a great deal of them have a where clause similiar to the below.

```
WHERE
    (CE.EnquiryDate >= @StartDate or @StartDate is null) and
    (CE.EnquiryDate <= @EndDate or @EndDate is null) and
    (CE.ClientID = @ClientID or @ClientID is null)
```

What concerns me is performance and the execution plans that are generated potentially causing issues down the track, i.e. if a plan is cached on first execution of the sp when only a clientid is passed then it is obviously going to be different to when a ClientID is not passed and a StartDate and EndDate are.

Am I going to be better off here splitting these off into multiple stored procedures or using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to get a new plan on each run? Just wondering what the best approach is in the early stages of development.

Comment: You can use dynamic SQL with `option (recompile)` to ensure an optimal execution plan for each run.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, but wouldn't that have the same effect in just adding it to the bottom of the sp than having to do dynamic SQL?

Comment: . . It is worth trying.  Perhaps SQL Server has gotten smarter about optimizing `where` clauses with `or` clauses with parameters.

Comment: Cheers for your comments Gordon

Comment: Aaron Bertrand wrote about this exact search: https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard treatment of this question is Erland Sommarskog's [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://T%E2%80%91SQLhttp://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).  Read that for a full discussion of the techniques and tradeoffs.

Since SQL 2008 SQL Server will optimize the query plan for this kind of query when using OPTION RECOMPILE.  The predicates corresponding to null parameters will be removed from the query during compilation.  So OPTION RECOMPILE is my default here, but if you have some search patterns you need to be super cheap, you may special-case them before a catch-all using OPTION RECOMPILE.

Something like:

```
IF (@StartDate is not null and @ClientId is not null)
BEGIN

    SELECT * 
    FROM T 
    WHERE
        (CE.EnquiryDate >= @StartDate)  and
        (CE.EnquiryDate <= @EndDate or @EndDate is null) and
        (CE.ClientID = @ClientID )

    RETURN
END


SELECT * 
FROM T 
WHERE
    (CE.EnquiryDate >= @StartDate or @StartDate is null) and
    (CE.EnquiryDate <= @EndDate or @EndDate is null) and
    (CE.ClientID = @ClientID or @ClientID is null)
WITH (OPTION RECOMPILE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response David, appreciate it. Could you provide an example surrounding "special-case"ing them based off what I list in my initial question? Cheers.

Comment: @James He did.That is the purpose of the first if statement - it's a "special case".

Comment: I added an example in response to @James's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
WHERE
    (CE.EnquiryDate >= ISNULL(@StartDate,CE.EnquiryDate)) and
    (CE.EnquiryDate <= ISNULL(@EndDate,CE.EnquiryDate)) and
    (CE.ClientID = ISNULL(@ClientID,CE.ClientID))
```

This can be used because of the "<=",">=" and "=" : not working with "<" or ">".

The goal is to avoir OR operator... Witch are so so slow. See execution plan.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra for further details about avoiding OR...

```
X OR Y = NOT (NOT X AND NOT Y)
```

Comment: Not better.  Both queries require a table scan, and the ISNULL _also_ requires that ISNULL(@param,col) expression be evaluated for each row.  The issue here more about whether to use the same plan for all combinations of criteria, or find a way to use different plans for different combinations of search criteria.

Comment: Not worse? Pleased to hear that from Microsoft ^^ RECOMPILE is clever to use in this case, but it tend to be used systematicaly.